# Requests from same client being queued in Apache, PHP stack

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, whm

I posted this on ServerFault, but I haven't received any answers yet.

I have a cloud server hosted at Rackspace with cPanel installed on it. I have only one PHP app hosted on this machine. I've noticed that when I'm uploading a large file or executing a request that takes a long time any concurrent requests from my current client get queued. This happens every single time. I tried hitting the app from another machine and was able to verify it is only handling one request at a time per client. I setup a phpinfo() page and that request was also queued, so I don't think it's an issue with the app. The reason I want it to handle multiple requests is because the app requires a lot of uploading of large file and it would be great if the user could work on something else in another window while the file is being uploaded.

I've been looking through the config file but haven't see anything that would be limiting this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: its how the session handler works

Comment: It may be browser based ? Ive seen a similar thing with Chrome